# TP-Link TL-WN722N V3, Kali 2018.2

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux

Will TP-Link TL-WN722N V3 (monitor mode) work with Kali Linux 2018.2? I couldn't find any information on the web regarding that, as all I can see that it does work on 2018.1

If not, where can I find the original 2018.1 Kali torrent download, I can't seem to find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

In Linux and any other OS the hardware (chip) powering/running the device is what matters. Brand, model, revisions, etc. are marketing.

https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N

Use the above to search for relevant information. [Kali Forums](https://forums.kali.org/) is the best support resource available. Be aware that the Kali community is not know for its political correctness or patience with newbies (been there, done that...). Kali is a highly specialized distro for professionals that already have an above average knowledge about Linux.